# How to deal with 1 partition separated into 2 parts?

Tags: partitioning

I am trying to keep my larger hard drive separated into 2 parts but I seem to have made an error when re-adjusting it resulting in the screenshot sample:

[image: partition screenshot]

Originally is was just 1 G: and 1 S: but after the change it became 2 Gs: and it became a simple volume.

Is there a way to join the 2 again so I can expand them more?

And further more even though I haven’t noticed a change is there a way to turn it back into a primary partition or should I just ignore it.

Comment: "is there a way to turn it back into a primary partition" - You should backup the partition before you do anything.

Comment: Is tjete data on these partitions?  If so, move all data from secing G partition  to the first one, then delete second partition and expand first one.

Comment: there is data on the G partition but im not sure how to move the data back to S. i do have an exteral harddrive aswell if it can help

Comment: Only one of those drives are accessible in File Explorer, determine which one is accessible, and the simply change the drive letter on the drive that cannot be accessed

Comment: You turned the drive into a dynamic disk. That's why you can't have primary partitions anymore. To get it out of dynamic disk state, the entire drive have to be rebuild, all partitions deleted and then convert it back to normal disk. If that is your goal, get an external drive, backup all data to it of Disk 1, remove all partitions and convert disk 1, then create the partitions with the sizes as you want.

Comment: @Ramhound given that both G partitions have the same name and letter, I have a suspicion, that this is a striped partition, and essentially both form one drive with all data on it.

Comment: @LPChip - I won't rule it out, but it's suppose to be a single 4 TB disk, and the three partitions together would make that about 3.7 TB usable storage.  DM indicates it's a simple partition.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah, they are simple volumes now, but given they have the same name and letter indicates it was a striped volume that was broken I think. Not sure...

Comment: Fortune i do have an external hard drive as stated earlier but I have a habit of over complicating things. 
Would doing a copy and paste from explorer to the external be the easiest way or is there a resource I referenced to that does it better?

Comment: You can just file copy everything, no need to use specialized backup software in this case. I recommend TeraCopy so you can verify that the files are fully copied.

Answer (score 3):

You turned your disk into a Dynamic disk.

Dynamic disks is a software RAID system where you can use multiple drives to create one larger partition as striped, or backup as mirrored.

In your case, it seems you created 2 striped partitions on the same disk, which forms one larger partitions, but Disk Manager shows them as simple volumes now, indicating this is a broken striped volume that you can reactivate, but it will slow down the disk as files are now spread over 2 partitions in different places on the same harddisk, so it is definitely wise to merge them back to one.

Unfortunately, that is not so simple.

Your best option right now, is to get an external drive of 4TB and backup all data from S: and G: to it. Then delete the 3 partitions. With an empty drive, right click the drive, and choose convert to normal disk. Now, you can create new Primary partitions in the sizes you want.

Comment: I'm not sure the striped/slow down part is true as there's also the spanned type volume.

Comment: @TomYan yeah, just spotted that myself. This is a striped volume that is in broken state, apparently.

Comment: It's not a "striped volume in broken state", it literally is just a plain spanned (concatenated) volume. I think it _might_ be possible to delete all but 1 of its spans and then convert things in-place to traditional GPT/MBR, but it's probably simpler to just rebuild from scratch.